# Change <a> for <input type="button"> with "download" property

Tags: javascript, canvas

I´m working in a very simple canvas-to-image exporter. You can check it here:
http://www.wilawara.com/downloadcanvas/

And it works but only works with:

```
<a id="download" download="CanvasDemo.png">Download as image</a>
```

And what I want is something like:

```
<input id="download" value="Download" download="CanvasDemo.png" onclick="download()">
```

Obviously this dont work and I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: download is not a function".

How can I change this label "a" for a button?

Sorry if my question is too basic, I´m still learning.

Thank you all.

Comment: `download` is not a legitimate HTML attribute. The reason why clicking on the anchor link *downloads* the image is because it has a base64-encoded PNG image in the `href` attribute. For the input element you have used, you have not specified a type (which means it defaults to `text`) and you have not defined `download()`.

Comment: I just checked that my example is not working in some browsers, thats why I´m looking for a new simple example to download a canvas as image, do you know any, Terry?

Comment: `download is not a legitimate HTML attribute` - it is for an anchor element - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes

Comment: I changed the example to not use 'download'. Now its easier but I still dont know how to use a button instead a label 'a': http://www.wilawara.com/downloadcanvas/

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on it to be input tag , and wont do some more action with the element you can make hidden `<a>` tag

```
<a id="download" download="CanvasDemo.png" style="display:none"></a>
```

and make the input that you mentioned look like you wish

```
<input id="input_download" value="Download" onclick="download()">
```

with download() function being function that invokes click on hidden `<a>` tag for example

```
  function download(){
    var tag=document.getElementById("download");
    tag.click()

}
```

Comment: does this work? I think the Browsers realy want the user to click on the link for safety

Comment: as far as i know this should work in all major browsers... not sure about IE tho :)

Comment: this code looks wrong. clicking the input would execute the `download` function, the `download` function clicks the input that triggered the function in the first place ... would this result in an infinite loop?

Comment: yes i see , i copied html from OPS question didnt noticed both have same ID . thanks for pointing out